# ggplot2 using open or closed circles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data like this (4703 lines):

```
a   b
100 1
101 0
102 0
103 1
104 1
```

I want to create a graph of circles, that plots the position and whether the position is 1 (black circle) or 0 (white circle).  I've been trying to play around with the following code:

```
data <- read.csv("/Users/Steve/Desktop/binary.csv")
ggplot(data, aes(x=a, y=b)) + 
+     geom_point(aes(shape=b)))
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape

Comment: Do you need circles or points?

Comment: Hmm.. I feel as if either is fine, as long as you can distinguish a point or circle as filled or open (depending on the 0 or 1 value.)

Answer (score 3):

As shapes are discrete objects you can't use a continuous variable to map to them. You need to convert `b` to a factor first.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=a, y=b, shape=as.factor(b))) + 
  geom_point(size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(21,19))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to do is by mentioning the `color` argument in `aes` as `factor` and then we can use `scale_color_manual` to specify the colors.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(a, b, color = factor(b))) + 
geom_point() + 
scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "black"))
```

[image]

PS - I have used  blue instead of white as it was difficult to see using white. You can change it according to your preference.